# Setting up multiple alarms , restarting alarm app when phone restarts

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to create an app where there would be multiple alarm(according to the will of user,so not definite ) but the i am unable to find any assistance. I also my app to run even if the phone is restarted. so in short i want to know about the operations of the usual alarm app that runs in the android phone

Comment: Search for "scheduling alarms in Android". It should show you some basic tutorials. You need `BroadcastReceiver` to start alarms after booting the phone.

Comment: yeah i got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BroadcastReceiver to start your service when your phone restarts. In your service then you can register your alarms. 
Here you can find an example:
[Autostart Service on Device Boot](http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/autostart-service-on-device-boot.html)